# Securing the videos in android application?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android application which can securely play the videos size 64gb (around 200 videos combine size is 64). I don't want anyone to copy(or to provide maximum security). I have thought of 2 methods to do it.

1) store all the videos in the android assets folder(64 gb i am not sure if it can accumulate). Then providing the secure flag to the page where they are running to stop the screen and video grab, also i am planning for a check in which the wifi is switched off before running of those videos so that screen sharing is not possible.

2) i bought a SD card yesterday in which there was some encrypted video file, they also provided an app through which we can access those files but, i was able to access those files and i am pretty sure that that can be decrypted. Also i don't know how to do this?

It will be a great help if you guys can suggest some help me sought out this.

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't feel that you can stop copying your video. Can you stop someone capture your video using a camera?

Comment: @BirendraSingh i want to provide maximum security, camera i know i can't stop